# Restart a single tomcat 7 webapp at a specific time?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat

Tomcat 7 is running on a Windows System. I need to restart one of the deployed web applications each day at a specific time.
Is there an option to do that via script or (even better) does tomcat offer a feature to do so?

Is it possible to use Curl to emulate the click on the reload button on the "list applications" page?

Comment: Why do you need to restart it?  Is restarting the webapp sufficient?  If so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800784/whats-an-easy-quick-way-to-reload-a-webapp-in-tomcat-in-dev-environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
curl --user admin:admin http://localhost:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/myapp
```

Doc here: [Manager App HOW-TO, Reload An Existing Application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application)

The **manager-script** role is required for the user as the documentation says:

> It would be quite unsafe to ship Tomcat with default settings that
>   allowed anyone on the Internet to execute the Manager application on
>   your server. Therefore, the Manager application is shipped with the
>   requirement that anyone who attempts to use it must authenticate
>   themselves, using a username and password that have the role
>   **manager-script** associated with them. Further, there is no username in
>   the default users file (`$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml`) that is
>   assigned this role. Therefore, access to the Manager application is
>   completely disabled by default.

Note: Tomcat 6 uses different management urls. ([Apache Tomcat 6.0 Manager App HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html))

Comment: Reload is not recommended in production environment. https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload